# AWS SES: Send email with same sender and recipient

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm using an AWS Lambda to process some data and if there is an error I would like to send an email to myself.

In AWS SES I registered two email addresses and did the email address verification request so my 2 email adresses are verified.

I created a policie in AWS IAM which is associate to mu AWS Lambda Role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:SendEmail",
                      "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:123456789:identity/test_addess_1@outlook.com",
                "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:123456789:identity/test_addess_2@outlook.com"
            ]
 }}
```

The is my code in Python:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    
    
    # SEND EMAIL
    SENDER = "test_addess_1@outlook.com"
    RECIPIENT = "test_addess_1@outlook.com"
    CHARSET = "UTF-8"


    BODY_HTML = """<html>
            <head></head>
            <body>Hello,
            </br></br>Test mail from lambda.
            </br>Please Test  MAIL
            </br></br></br>Best regards.
            </br></br></br>An error occurs for session id 
            </br><b>ERROR</b>
            </br></br>CloudWatch Logs:
            </br>{}
            </body></html>"""  
    # try to specific session id

    SUBJECT = "Test mail from AWS Lambda"

    client = boto3.client('ses', region_name="eu-west-1")
    # Try to send the email.
    
    # Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML,
                }
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT,
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER,
    )
    print("ok")
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

What I don't understand is why I can successfully send an email from address_1 to address_2 but I can't send an email from address_1 to address_1 ?

In gmail or outlook we can do that but in my case from a lambda it is not working..

Thanks for your help! Regards

Comment: I was also trying to send email to the same address as sender address. I just learned that even if the domain is verified for AWS SES, the recipient email address (which is same as the sender email address in our cases) also needs to be verified. (This note is clearly written in AWS SES console on the Verified Identities page, but I didn't saw it; I saw it after verifying the email address! ‍♂️